# Tor and Firefox not opening correctly

Tags: firefox, browser, tor

My firefox is opening as tor browser when tor is already opened and same is happening for tor when firefox is already openend

Answer (score -1):

First of all make your firefox as a default browser. Then you need to press and hold the shift key and at the same time double click on firefox icon. It will ask to reset firefox. Click on reset ...That will resolve your issue.